# How to grab a value on a page so I can perform an action on it and validate the value has changed

Tags: cypress

I'm looking to load a page up, grab the text content of an element, store it, perform an action on the page and then grab the value again and check if it has changed.

I know how to do everything but storing the value of an element.

Is this possible is Cypress or would I have to just use plain JS to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aliases for this. You can do something like this:

```js
cy.get('selector').invoke('text').as('text1')

//perform some actions

cy.get('@text1').then((text1) => {
  cy.get('selector').invoke('text').then((text2) => {
    expect(text1).to.equal(text2)
  })
})
```